# GNU make - how to keep track of max number simultaneous makes

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I'm using `make` 3.81 on Windows which doesn't have the [job-server](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/) capability so in order to run my entire makefile project in parallel, I have to do this hack:

`make all -j 16 MAKE="make -j 16"`

This does NOT mean there will be at most 16 jobs because make 3.81 **on Windows** doesn't have the capability to limit the maximum number of makes, hence my hack.

While my make project is running how do I get an upper limit on the number of makes simultaneously active?

Comment: If you're asking, how do you get make to tell you how many makes are running right now, you can't.  Make doesn't even know that, since all the sub-makes could themselves be running more sub-sub-makes, etc.  What are you trying to do with that information?

Comment: @MadScientist this build will be running on a big server and its managers will want to know how swamped it'll be. It'll be more people than me running this hacked `make` build. I'm honestly not sure if this'll be an actual issue.

Comment: Well, your only option is to upgrade to a newer version of GNU make where jobserver support is available.  Even then you can't find out how many jobs are currently running, but at least you could create an upper bound on the number of jobs that _could_ be running.  To find out how many jobs are actually running you'll need to use something outside of GNU make.  On a UNIX system you could write a script to run "ps" and count the number of compiler processes.  Presumably you can find a similar thing on Windows, or write one in Python or Perl or whatever.

Comment: @MadScientist unfortunately we have to use the `make` that comes with our SDK :(

Comment: Well, then you're out of luck.  You'll have to use some external method of tracking number of processes, as above.  Or you could essentially implement the jobserver feature on your own, by modifying your makefiles so that every recipe first runs a little program that obtained a token (using some kind of semaphore feature) and released it when the recipe finished.

Comment: @MadScientist hmm. Didn't know that was possible. Sounds like that's the answer :) Go ahead and set